# Concatenatee two Lists in c++ in O(1) Complexity

Tags: c++, data-structures

We can concatenate two Linked List in O(1) time if we know the last element.
So, Is there any way to concatenate two List in `C++` using built-in data structures or I have to implement linked list myself then use it?

Comment: Use the splice method.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
std::list<int> l1 = create();
std::list<int> l2 = create();
l1.splice(l1.end(), l2);
```

Note that this empties `l2` and moves its elements to `l1`.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code this will merge two lists

```
list<int> list1 = { 5,9,0,1,3,4 };
list<int> list2 = { 8,7,2,6,4 }; 
list1.merge(list2);
```

Comment: `merge()` is not `O(1)`, and only works on sorted lists, which yours are not